# Using md-list - Not aligned correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm running to a problem using md-list.

When it is the first time I access the page it looks like this: [Bad aligned image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc1tN.png)

It is very subtle but "Time" isn't aligned with the md-cards below.

Bus as soon as I use the "resize arrow" at Chrome it works just as I want, like this: [Good aligned Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbFWm.png)

I've tried a lot of things but I have no clue what might be the issue. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
  div#Time(layout="column"  flex="100" layout-align="center center")
   h1 Time
   md-list(flex="100" layout-wrap layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-align="space-around center")
     md-list-item(ng-repeat="pessoa in $ctrl.listaPessoas")
       md-card(layout="column" flex-gt-sm="100")
        img.md-card-image(ng-src="{{pessoa.img}}")
        md-card-title(layout="column")
          md-card-title-text(flex="100" layout="column" layout-align="center center")
            h3 {{pessoa.nome}}
        md-card-actions(layout="row" layout-align="center center")
          a(target='_blank' href='{{pessoa.twitter}}')
            md-button.md-icon-button(aria-label="twitter button")
              i.fa.fa-twitter
          a(target='_blank' href='{{pessoa.linkedin}}')
            md-button.md-icon-button(aria-label="linkedin button")
            i.fa.fa-linkedin
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example? Codepen?

Comment: @kuhnroyal tks for the message. I don't think Codepen will exhibit the same behavior. The best example are in the printscreens

Comment: can not able to generate the error you are getting. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/LxOZQX

Comment: Try using a grid list, the list is not really meant to be used this way.